# MySQL Workbench - Connect to a Localhost

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I just installed MySQL Workbench and there are no connections available for my localhost server.  When I try to make one, I get an error popup. Has anyone experienced something like this before and would be able to help me out?

Here is what it looks like on start up:

[image: MySQL home page]

And if I try to make a connection myself it shows this:
[image]

Any help would be much appreciated - thanks!

Comment: Did you install MySQL and if so, are the services running?

Comment: @JamesSmith - I just installed Workbench. What else do I need to install?

Comment: for me it was just because i had not defined a password. after setting it i could connect with no problem. from workbench.
resetting a password https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MysqlPasswordReset

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Sounds like you only installed the MySQL Client Tools (MySQL Workbench). You have to install the MySQL Database server, configure and start it.

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/

You probably want the MySQL Community Server download.

Comment: I guess I should mention that this is my first time using MySQL. If i didn't make it obvious... Thanks anyway!

Comment: @scapegoat17 I strongly recommend using the [MySQL Installer for Windows](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/windows/installer/) which makes it extremely easy to install all necessary components and also helps you to check for updates. And if there are no connections yet and MySQL Workbench finds running servers it will automatically create connections to each server found.

Comment: @MikeLischke - That is what i went ahead and did. Thanks!

Comment: @James i'm having the same problem but i did install the server and it is runnng.

Comment: Thank you a thousand times! :)

Comment: Or XAMPP has not been started, if it is XAMPP that is being used instead.

Answer (score 26):

For Win users:

Check if the MYSQL service is running or not. To check the service is running or not. Use the below steps:

- Step1: Open the Services Desktop app from the Windows menu.

[image]

- Step 2: Then search the list of services to identify the name of the
  MySQL service.
  [image]
- Step 3: Right-click on the service name to open the menu.
- Step 4: Start the service if it is not running.

Comment: this method worked for me, thanks

Comment: Thanks for the quick fix guideline!!!

Comment: This worked! Thanks for the quick and simple guide.

Answer (score 6):

**Solution**:

1. Open up your **mysql installer**.
2. Click on **Reconfigure**, shown in *red*. [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FUYnk.jpg]
3. In that, Click on next until you enter the **Accounts and Roles** tab.
4. Create a password and then, click next for the rest of the tabs.

Now, try again!

Answer (score 4):

Its Worked for me on Windows

First i installed and started **XAMPP Control Panel**
[image]

Clicked for Start under Actions for MySQL. And below is my Configuration for MySQL (MySQL Workbench 8.0 CE) Connections
[image]
 And it got connected with Test DataBase

Answer (score 1):

If xamp already installed on your computer user these settings

[image]

Comment: If you don't need advanced server settings use Xamp. Easy and straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem and I just realized that if in the server you see the user in the menu SERVER -> USERS AND PRIVILEGES and find the user who has % as HOSTNAME, you can use it instead the root user.

That's all

Answer (score 0):

You need to install mysql server for your machine first. Once done, you will be able to add local db details to it.

```
For e.g. IP: 127.0.0.1
port: 3306
user: root
pass: pass of root which you have set
```

Here is the link on step by step guide for linux.

https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/install-mysql-server-on-the-ubuntu-operating-system/

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CmPho.png)

I think you want to config your database server firstly after the installation, as shown in picture, you can reconfigure MySql server

Answer (score 0):

1. Install MySQL installer.
2. Select Add... from the right side and install the latest version of MySQL server.

I hope this will work. It worked for me. Thank You.

Comment: where to install the mysql server?? where is that right side?

Answer (score 0):

services->mysql (on left corner click on start)

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34563378)

Answer (score -1):

if you are using localhost database, try port 3306

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. The screenshot shows which port is currently used, and that is 3306 already