# Tomcat started in STS but unable to connect to http://localhost:8080/Portal

Tags: java, tomcat

I configured Tomcat Server 6.0.24 in STS and started successfully

But when I am trying to connect to http://localhost:8080/ it is giving me the following error

HTTP Status 404 - /

type Status report

message /

description The requested resource is not available.

Apache Tomcat/7.0.57

Any Solution, unfortunately i'm a newbie...my Java developer isn't available for the next one more week and I've to do the HTML modification in the portal.

I need a solution to fix this.
I tried to switch server location but Tomcat never starts. I closed the STS and went into localhost:8080 then my tomcat page shows up.

But the problem is only when STS is open i get 404 error.

Comment: Do you have tomcat started as a service? Ensure you're only starting one instance of tomcat. Post the console log when you switch server location and tomcat does not start

Comment: [link]https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9zaCxxvsStkbXRvLXpSdjZvUjg/view?usp=sharing
Here is the log

Comment: Please find below the Tomcat error log But I didnt get anything in console log
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9zaCxxvsStkX2NhY1M5cEJFd2c/view?usp=sharing

Comment: In the first log I only see errors related to database connections (Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)). In the second there are errors referring to a non-existent path (The system cannot find the path specified)

Comment: @Javier Molla okie, so have any solution what could be done?
Also, I've setup a domain name in localhost, when I type that domain name I only get Apache page but my java developer has given me a ports.conf file for apache I'm not sure how to configure this.
Earlier it used to work with the domain name but my system crashed and had to re-install everything. But, now my developer isn't here I'm totally stuck.

Comment: For the first error you'll have to check that mysql is installed and running. Also, the password should match with the one your project uses. For the second error, I think you're switching the server location to one that does not exists, maybe?

Comment: Alright I got it, I think mysql isnt configured but I've MYSQL workbench installed.
May be I'll use the same settings of server without switching locations.
But could you help me how do I add the database to MYSQL workbench I'm totally new to dynamic sites I only develop static sites.
but now I've to work on UI part of this.

Comment: Check this question for installing MySQL and connecting with Workbench: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20431491/mysql-workbench-connect-to-a-localhost. If you have more questions, post them and someone will help you