# Vagrant configuration will not be effected with installing "MySQL Database server"

Tags: vagrant, localhost, mysql-workbench, vagrant-windows, database-server

I have already configured `MySQL Workbench` with `vagrant` and accessing sites as `www-devsite.com`. I need to have install new sites on localhost as we do by using WAMP/XAMP on windows but I don't know **following installations will effect or damage my existing configurations (`MySQL Workbench` and `Vagrant`)**.

1. if I install "MySQL Database Server" [as required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20431491/mysql-workbench-connect-to-a-localhost).
2. If I'd like to install WAMP/XAMP

**Please confirm the possibilities for both scenarios**