# MySQL Workbench could not detect any MySQL server running. Solution?

Tags: mysql, server, mysql-workbench

I have just downloaded MySQL from https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/installer/ .I have downloaded MySQL workbench, MySQL server, MySQL router, ect. When I open MySQL workbench all I see is "MySQL Workbench could not detect any MySQL server running. This means that MySQL is not installed or is not running". I have already tried the solutions of XAMPP changing the ports or using task manager and stop and start again. Nothing is working. I have been stuck on this problem for hours[My Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wdbnv.png)

Comment: start you server before trying to run MySql WorkBench.

Comment: it should have started as service, so check th mysql error log to see if something is prventing it from startinng, also try to reconfigure the mysql server if you hadn't done it alredy

Comment: @bigtheo How do I start the server?

Comment: I have just tried https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/windows-start-command-line.html and nothing happens. I can't even seem to find C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\data . MySQL server is not installed properly?

Comment: I have tried starting MySQL server and nothing is working

Comment: @nbk I can't seem to locate the file. I can't seem to locate it? I've searched all the files

Comment: you start by startuijg the servce manually, there you find the oölaction of the ini file that configure mysql and in that you find the location of the error file

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL Workbench - Connect to a Localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20431491/mysql-workbench-connect-to-a-localhost)